# Программное изменение размеров содержимого View

Tags: ios, swift

Пишу приложение "Калькулятор". Установил размеры кнопок для 3,5 дюймового экрана. Хочу сделать программное "растягивание" размеров до пропорций 4, 4,7 и 5,5 дюймов.
Все работает как нужно при нажатии на кнопку Button, но при перестроении экрана (отрисовке цифр в текстовом поле) размеры возвращаются к исходным.

Как "закрепить" произошедшее масштабирование?

Также не могу понять как сделать чтоб изменение размеров происходило при запуске приложения.
На приведенном изображении кнопки должны растягиваться и закрывать пустое пространство справа у 4in экрана.

[image: целевой экран]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var BTN: [UIButton]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func But(sender: AnyObject) {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let scaleX = screenSize.width / 480
    let scaleY = screenSize.height / 320
    if scaleX == 1 && scaleY == 1 { return }

    for btn in  BTN {
        btn.frame.origin.x *= scaleX
        btn.frame.origin.y *= scaleY
        btn.frame.size.height *= scaleY
        btn.frame.size.width *= scaleX
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему не использовать auto layout? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: Если требуется выровнять 2-3 элемента - все получается отлично и с layout. У меня же много кнопок различного размера ( служебные, также "ноль" была в два раза шире ). При использовании выравниваний и привязок размеры объектов будут изменяться, а хотелось бы все оставить в прежнем виде.

Comment: Используйте Size Classes: https://habrahabr.ru/post/235181/

Comment: В Size Class только два варианта, 3.5, 4.0, 4,7 и 5.5 дюймов. А тут получается что должно быть 4 варианта каждый со своими настройками выравнивания и размеров элементов. Я понимаю, конечно, что с подобных калькуляторов все начинали. Быть может кто-нибудь выложит свои исходники с примером  размещения большого количества элементов разных размеров ?

Comment: @Alex в скрине примера они все одинаковые. И что значит оставить в прежнем виде? В любом случае на разных экранах будет по-разному.

Comment: VAndrJ, задумывалось что кнопка "ноль" - в суммарную ширину кнопок "1" и "2". Два столбца кнопок справа - несколько шире цифровых. Высота текстового поля больше чем у кнопок. Задача в том чтоб сделать макет экрана для 3,5in и все эти элементы увеличивались исключительно на множитель роста экрана в X и Y направлениях.

Comment: Что значит в Size Class только два варианта? В Size Class Вы можете сделать UI для любого экрана и для любой ориентации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстро набросал в IB пример.

Исходники: https://github.com/VAndrJ/CalcExampleForSO

Краткая инструкция (не претендую, что все правильно, да и объяснять не мастер):

1. Добавляем первый элемент(вывод результата) на View
2. Расставляем Constraints: отступы сверху, справа и слева.
3. Добавляем втрой ряд элементов, расставляем отступы по горизонтали, для первого элемента делаем отступ сверху от первого ряда. Все остальные центрируем относительно первого 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Копируем этот ряд и вставляем 3 раза
5. Добавляем необходимые отступы по вертикали и от границ
6. Расставляем для первых элементов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Все элементы ряда ровняем относительно первого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. Для служебных(которых необходимо) устанавливаем множитель:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
9. Результат одинаков на всех устройствах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: VAndrJ, спасибо! Разобрался с маштабированием, все действительно просто и через код делать ничего не нужно